# build SQL dynamic query with psycopg2 python library and using good conversion type tools

Tags: python, postgresql, type-conversion, postgis, psycopg2

I have some problem to design a good algorithm which use specification of psycopg2 library described [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation)

I want to build a dynamic query equal to this string :

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0.0 0.0,20.0 0.0,20.0 20.0,0.0 20.0,0.0 0.0))');
```

As you can see, my POLYGON object contain multiple point, read in a simple csv file some.csv which contain :

```
0.0;0.0
20.0;0.0
20.0;20.0
0.0;20.0
0.0;0.0
```

So i build the query dynamically, function of the number of line/data in the csv.

Here my program to generate the SQL Query string to execute :

```
import psycopg2
import csv 

# list of points
lXy = []

DSN= "dbname='testS' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)

curs = conn.cursor()

def genPointText(curs,x,y):
    generatedPoint = "%s %s" % (x,y)
    return generatedPoint

#Lecture fichier csv
polygonFile = open('some.csv', 'rb')
readerCSV = csv.reader(polygonFile,delimiter = ';')

for coordinates in readerCSV:
    lXy.append(genPointText(curs,float(coordinates[0]),float(coordinates[1])))

# function of list concatenation by separator
def convert(myList,separator):
    return separator.join([str(i) for i in myList])

# construct simple query with psycopg
def genPolygonText(curs,l):
    # http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation
    generatedPolygon = "POLYGON((%s))" % convert(l, ",")
    return generatedPolygon

def executeWKT(curs,geomObject,srid):
    try:
            # geometry ST_GeomFromText(text WKT, integer srid);
        finalWKT = "SELECT ST_GeomFromText('%s');" % (geomObject) 
        print finalWKT
        curs.execute(finalWKT)
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError,err:
        print "ERROR = " , err

polygonQuery = genPolygonText(curs,lXy)
executeWKT(curs,polygonQuery,4326)
```

As you can see, that's works, but this way is not correct because of conversion problem between python object and sql postgresql object.

In the documentation, i see only example to feed and convert data for static query. Do you know an "elegant" way to create correct string with correct type in a dynamic build for query ?

UPDATE 1 :

As you can see, when i use psycopg type transformation function on this simple example, i have error like this :

```
query = "ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 52.146542 19.050557, 52.148430 19.045527, 52.149525 19.045831, 52.147400 19.050780, 52.147400 19.050780, 52.146542 19.050557))',4326)"
name = "my_table"

try:
    curs.execute('INSERT INTO %s(name, url, id, point_geom, poly_geom) VALUES (%s);', (name,query))
except psycopg2.ProgrammingError,err:
    print "ERROR = " , err
```

Error equal :

```
ERROR =  ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « E'my_table' »
LINE 1: INSERT INTO E'my_table'(name, poly_geom) VALUES (E'ST_GeomFr...
```

UPDATE 2 :

Final code which work thanks to stackoverflow users !

```
#info lib : http://www.initd.org/psycopg/docs/
import psycopg2
# info lib : http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
import csv 

# list of points
lXy = []

DSN= "dbname='testS' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'"

print "Opening connection using dns:", DSN
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)

curs = conn.cursor()

def genPointText(curs,x,y):
    generatedPoint = "%s %s" % (x,y)
    return generatedPoint

#Lecture fichier csv
polygonFile = open('some.csv', 'rb')
readerCSV = csv.reader(polygonFile,delimiter = ';')

for coordinates in readerCSV:
    lXy.append(genPointText(curs,float(coordinates[0]),float(coordinates[1])))

# function of list concatenation by separator
def convert(myList,separator):
    return separator.join([str(i) for i in myList])

# construct simple query with psycopg
def genPolygonText(l):
    # http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation
    generatedPolygon = "POLYGON((%s))" % convert(l, ",")
    return generatedPolygon

def generateInsert(curs,tableName,name,geomObject):
    curs.execute('INSERT INTO binome1(name,geom) VALUES (%s, %s);' , (name,geomObject))


def create_db_binome(conn,name):

    curs = conn.cursor()

    SQL = (
        "CREATE TABLE %s"
        " ("
        " polyname character varying(15),"
        " geom geometry,"
        " id serial NOT NULL,"
        " CONSTRAINT id_key PRIMARY KEY (id)"
        " )" 
        " WITH ("
        " OIDS=FALSE"
        " );"
        " ALTER TABLE %s OWNER TO postgres;"
        ) %(name,name)
    try:
      #print SQL
      curs.execute(SQL)

    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError,err:
      conn.rollback()
      dropQuery = "ALTER TABLE %s DROP CONSTRAINT id_key; DROP TABLE %s;" % (name,name)
      curs.execute(dropQuery)
      curs.execute(SQL)

    conn.commit()

def insert_geometry(polyname,tablename,geometry):

    escaped_name = tablename.replace('""','""')

    try:
        test = 'INSERT INTO %s(polyname, geom) VALUES(%%s, ST_GeomFromText(%%s,%%s))' % (escaped_name)
        curs.execute(test, (tablename, geometry, 4326))
        conn.commit()
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError,err:
        print "ERROR = " , err

################
# PROGRAM MAIN #
################

polygonQuery = genPolygonText(lXy)
srid = 4326
table = "binome1"

create_db_binome(conn,table)
insert_geometry("Berlin",table,polygonQuery)
insert_geometry("Paris",table,polygonQuery)

polygonFile.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: What's the generated query text from your program? And what's the error message?

Comment: I update with simple example and an error trace :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass a table name as a parameter. You probably could've seen this immediately if you'd just looked at the PostgreSQL error log.

The table name you're trying to pass through psycopg2 as a parameter is being escaped, producing a query like:

```
INSERT INTO E'my_table'(name, url, id, point_geom, poly_geom) VALUES (E'ST_GeomFromText(''POLYGON(( 52.146542 19.050557, 52.148430 19.045527, 52.149525 19.045831, 52.147400 19.050780, 52.147400 19.050780, 52.146542 19.050557))'',4326)');'
```

This isn't what you intended and won't work; you can't escape a table name like a literal. You must use normal Python string interpolation to construct dynamic SQL, you can only use parameterized statement placeholders for actual literal values.

```
params = ('POLYGON(( 52.146542 19.050557, 52.148430 19.045527, 52.149525 19.045831, 52.147400 19.050780, 52.147400 19.050780, 52.146542 19.050557))',4326)
escaped_name = name.replace('"",'""')
curs.execute('INSERT INTO "%s"(name, url, id, point_geom, poly_geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(%%s,%%s));' % escaped_name, params)
```

See how I've interpolated the name directly to produce the query string:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(name, url, id, point_geom, poly_geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(%s,%s));
```

(`%%` gets converted to plain `%` by % substitution). Then I'm using that query with the string defining the `POLYGON` and the other argument to `ST_GeomFromText` as query parameters.

I haven't tested this, but it should give you the right idea and help explain what's wrong.

**BE EXTEMELY CAREFUL** when doing string interpolation like this, it's an easy avenue for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I've done very crude quoting in the code shown above, but I'd want to use a proper identifier quoting function if your client library offers one.

Comment: Thanks ! I update my problem with a complete working solution/program with creation of database, based on your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Now that 2.7 is on PyPi here is is an example for a dynamic query.

In this example I'll assume the polygon as dictionary from your csv file. Keys could be name, url, id, point_geom, poly_geom as mentioned above but they won't matter really as long as the table structure contains the same keys.

There's probably a way to shorten this but I hope this clarifies the use of the sql functions, namely `sql.SQL`, `sql.Identifier`, and `sql.Placeholder` and how to concatenate a list of strings `sql.SQL('..').join(list())`.

```
from psycopg2 import sql
table = 'my_table'
polygon = Polyogon.from_file()  # or something
column_list = list()
value_list = list()

# Convert the dictionary to lists
for column, value in polygon.items():
    column_list.append(sql.Identifier(column))  # Convert to identifiers
    value_list.append(value)

# Build the query, values will be inserted later
query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({}) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING").format(
                sql.Identifier(table),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(column_list),  # already sql.Identifier
                sql.SQL(', ').join([sql.Placeholder()] * len(value_list)))

# Execute the cursor
with postgres.cursor() as p_cursor:
    # execute requires tuples and not a list
    p_cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(value_list))
```

Reference: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to use psycopg2 2.7's new [`sql` module](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) which includes an `Identifier` object. This allows you to dynamically specify SQL identifiers in a safe way.

Unfortunately 2.7 is not on PyPi yet (2.6.2 as of writing).

Until then, psycopg2 cover this under the heading "How can I pass field/table names to a query?"
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#problems-with-type-conversions

You can pass SQL identifiers in along with data values to the execute function by using the `AsIs` function.

Note: this provides **NO security**. It is as good as using a format string, which is not recommended.
The only real advantage of this is you encourage future code to follow the execute + data style. You can also easily search for `AsIs` in future.

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
<snip>
with transaction() as cur:
    # WARNING: not secure
    cur.execute('SELECT * from %(table)s', {'table': AsIs('mytable')})
```