# specify table name for SQL statement by using user specifed name all of this will be in a python script

Tags: python, html, sql, python-2.7

how do i do to specify a table name from an HTML form to a postgres database SQL query?

```
abc:[
{
 sql:"select count(*) from some_database",
count:"100"
}]
```

i have been looking at things like meta data and sqlalchemy because i am using python. and the sql statement is in a python file. can u suggest me any way to do this?

dont mind the code its just for the sake

my real problem was i had a SELECT query but the table to select the data from needs to be specified by the user..from an html file..

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292218/build-sql-dynamic-query-with-psycopg2-python-library-and-using-good-conversion-t

Comment: Thanks am gonna try this :))